# Format null DateTime in DataGridView WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview, formatting

how to format null datetime in datagridview?
I create the datagridviewcolumn programmatically, in the form load

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn updatedDateColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
updatedDateColumn.DataPropertyName = "UpdatedDate";
updatedDateColumn.HeaderText = "Updated Date";
updatedDateColumn.Name = "UpdatedDate";
updatedDateColumn.DefaultCellStyle = style;
```

the problem is when the update date value is null
datagridview display 01/01/0001 12:00:00

I've tried to edit

```
style.NullValue = string.Empty;
```

but it didn't work
how to solve this?
thanks

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type, so it can never be `null`. What is it that you are putting into the cells exactly?

Comment: yes you're right, when I get the updatedDate from database, I check if updatedDate is null, I assign updatedDate with DateTime.MinValue.
but If I don't apply the style, the updatedDate didn't show 01/01/0001 12:00:00

Comment: Why not use `Nullable<DateTime>` instead? That would seem to solve the issue and feels more appropriate too.

Comment: could you please show me the example?

Comment: I can't because I have no idea what your code looks like. You need to change the type of the property that stores the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL to set null date to null in sql server and set the NullValue property of datagridviewCellStyle to string.Empty ; like this one in sql server

```
ISNULL(DateColumnName , NULL) and set style.NullValue = string.Empty
```

in dataGridViewCellStyle